# Retrieving output and exit code of a coprocess

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I have to retrieve both the exit code and output of a coprocess in `bash`. So I ended up with the following, but weirdly enough, I don't know why it works:

```
coproc { sleep 30 && echo "Output" && exit 3; }
# Saving the coprocess's PID for later, as COPROC_PID apparently unsets when its finished
COPROC_PID_backup=$COPROC_PID

# Retrieving the coprocess's output
output=$(cat <&$COPROC)

# Retrieving the coprocess's exit code
wait $COPROC_PID_backup

# Echoing out the results
echo $?
echo $output
```

And I "successfully" get the following output:

```
3
Output
```

There are quite a few things that I don't understand here:

1. How is `cat` able to read the coprocess's output from that file descriptor? I thought these were process dependent. So that if `bash` expands `$COPROC` to say `51`, then this rediction should mean "make `stdin` read from **this process's** `FD 51`'s stream";
2. Calling a command between the `coproc` and `cat` commands makes the latter fail if the coprocess has ended, giving the error `bash: $COPROC : ambiguous redirection`, for example if I use a while loop to wait:

```
coproc { sleep 30 && echo "Output" && exit 3; }

while kill -0 $COPROC_PID_backup &>/dev/null ; do
    sleep 1
done

output=$(cat <&$COPROC) # Fails
```

3. How is `wait` capable to grab the exit code of the coprocess, as it is already ended. Is stored until its read once? If so, where?

I must have misunderstood how redirections work, as I really don't understand how `cat` is able to get the coprocess's output.

P.S: Testing is done in an interactive shell.

Comment: (1) `cat` is forked off of the shell that starts it. It inherits that shell's file descriptors, including the handle on the coprocess.

Comment: (3) Processes still live in the process table as zombies until their child calls `wait()`, `waitpid()`, etc (that's what the Z entries are -- programs that exited, but whose parents haven't retrieved the tombstone recording how they died).

Comment: I'm not really sure that there's a good question here; it's not "how do I do X?", but "why does X work?", and there's a large body of explanation on [meta] of why "explain this code to me" questions are off-topic (basically, the rabbit hole goes indefinitely deep unless there's a solid enough explanation of *precisely* what the question is about to let someone stop explaining).

Comment: 2. I can't reproduce this when I add a `sleep 1` before the `output=..` line

Comment: *nod* -- (2) smells like a bug in a specific version of bash (which could very well be on-topic here if they gave a proper [mcve] for it), but we'd need to know what that version was. Though it could be something different -- I wonder if the OP was testing at an interactive shell, which reaped the job table (aka handled the `SIGCHILD` received when the subprocess died, removing zombies from the table). Again, though, it's very much in "need specific, detailed repro instructions" territory.

Comment: (ugh, "until their child calls" should have been "until their parent calls" -- with the understanding that when a process's parent dies, *their* parent inherits it, until it eventually gets adopted by PID 1 and reaped).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `cat <&$COPROC`
>
> So that if bash expands `$COPROC` to say `51`, then this rediction should mean "make stdin read from this process's FD 51's stream";

No, that means: fork a separate process (which will *inherit* all the open fds from its parent), make fd 0 (stdin) an alias of fd 51 (`dup2(51, 0)`, that's what `<&` does) then exec `cat`, which will again inherit all open fds (including stdin = 0), *except* those marked with `O_CLOEXEC` (which I bet is the case for `$COPROC` = 51).

Notice that `$COPROC` is actually an array: using an array as a simple variable in `bash` will retrieve its first element: `$COPROC` is the same as `${COPROC[0]}`, ie its reading end.

> Putting a `sleep` command between the `coproc` and `cat` commands makes the latter fail, giving the error bash: `$COPROC : ambiguous redirection`;

`bash` will unset the `$COPROC` variable (or whatever the coprocess name) as soon as the coprocess has terminated. So `cat <&$COPROC` will generate the same error as `cat <&$no_such_variable`. Example:

```
$ coproc foo { true; }; sleep 1; echo foo=$foo; true <&$foo
[5] 4658
[5]   Done                    coproc foo { true; }
foo=
bash: $foo: ambiguous redirect
$ coproc foo { sleep 2; }; sleep 1; echo foo=$foo; true <&$foo
[5] 4664
foo=61
```

In the second case, the coprocess will outlive the `sleep 1`.

> How is `wait` capable to grab the exit code of the coprocess, as it is already ended. Is stored until its read once? If so, where?

`bash` will call itself the `wait(2)`, `waitpid(2)` or similar system call, and store the status of the child process *somewhere* in its memory. Notice that bash is greedily waiting its children; it doesn't leave zombie processes sticking around until the script cares to `wait` for them (as some comments suggest). That's why `$!` or your `$COPROC_PID_backup` are not always reliable -- they could've been already reused for another process by the time you're using them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've done further testing and have added an example to my second question.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Sorry if it's a bit rambling ;-)